# @produces annotation in RESTful and java

Tags: java, rest, jersey

How does the following code creates a XML type response without use of any JAXBContext and Marshaller?

```
@GET
@Path("sayHello")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public HelloXML sayHello(@QueryParam("name") String name){
    HelloXML helloXML=new HelloXML(name);
    return helloXML;
}
```

Comment: Please read this link.
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html

Comment: thank you @ShivV . the content cleared my doubt

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes, you're using the Jersey API, and I'm guessing Jersey uses a serializing API (like JacksonXML or other).
I have more experience with RestExpress myself and it uses JacksonXML.
I may be wrong and if so, please correct me.